# Q : How to nginx Conditional proxy_pass based on HTTP Header

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

How to do conditional proxy_pass based on custom HTTP Header

Suppose I have 4 nginx Engine run in my private network, lets Call it : web1, web2, web3, web4.

I have a main nginx server, sit betwen internet and my private network, lets call it : Main_Web

At the same host as Main_web, I have python based authentication service run on port 5000, lets callit auth_backend.py.

as an authentication backend this auth_backend.py will return 401 if user is ilegal.
But for legal user it will return a redirect (302) to internal location (/afterauth) AND also add custom HTTP Header,

i.e:`X-HTTP-BACKEND = 'http://web4/thispage?var=2'`

---

/etc/nginx/conf.d/default

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;
    add_header X-Backend $http_x_backend;
    location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000 ;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

    location /afterauth/ {
    set $my_next_proxy $upstream_http_x_backend;
    proxy_pass http://$my_next_proxy ;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

}
```

auth backend script

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from flask import Flask, request, make_response, redirect
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hello_world():
    resp = make_response('Flask make_response', 200)
    #resp = redirect('afterauth/mykey=NEXTKEY')
    resp.headers['X-Backend']='192.168.100.1:5001/?key=MYKEY01'
    return resp

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Last Debug at https://pastebin.com/DwcgVeuN

at line 114 - 126 of 'last debug', I got :

```
    2017/10/13 03:22:53 [debug] 1737#1737: *9 http proxy header: "X-Backend: 192.168.100.1:5001/?key=MYKEY01"
    2017/10/13 03:22:53 [debug] 1737#1737: *9 http proxy header: "Server: Werkzeug/0.12.2 Python/2.7.9"
    2017/10/13 03:22:53 [debug] 1737#1737: *9 http proxy header: "Date: Thu, 12 Oct 2017 20:22:53 GMT"
    2017/10/13 03:22:53 [debug] 1737#1737: *9 http proxy header done
    2017/10/13 03:22:53 [debug] 1737#1737: *9 HTTP/1.1 302 FOUND
    Server: nginx/1.13.5
    Date: Thu, 12 Oct 2017 20:22:53 GMT
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
    Content-Length: 253
    Connection: keep-alive
    Location: http://192.168.100.48/afterauth/mykey=NEXTKEY
    X-Backend: 192.168.100.1:5001/?key=MYKEY01
```

How to put that '192.168.100.1:5001/?key=MYKEY01' as proxy_pass url ?

Sincerely

-bino-

Comment: take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878334/nginx-conditional-proxy-pass looks like the solution is to use the EVIL if statement.

Comment: @FedericoGalli, thankyou for your verry prompt response. Actual I try to understand that but I didn't make it. currently my main Nginx give : 'invalid URL prefix in "http://"'

Nginx debug log is at https://pastebin.com/JhcbE4bR
Nginx config is at : https://pastebin.com/W545mxg0
The auth backeend script at https://pastebin.com/J4tniFGM

Comment: Have you defined all the backends on the http section?

Comment: @FedericoGalli , No. I want it dynamicaly. But I don't know how to do it. My try is shown at https://pastebin.com/W545mxg0 line 10-12. My authentication backend  (line 6) is succesfully called, And It 'tried' to return 200 status and 'x_backend' custom header with jus a static url (https://pastebin.com/J4tniFGM line 9-10)

Comment: I just edit the question to try to make it clearer.